# Capture basics using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html2canvas

I'm using html2canvas. How do I capture DIV `aaa` and print it in canvas `avatar` inside DIV `tt`?

```
<div id="aaa">
    aaaaa<br />
    bbbbb
</div>

<div id="tt"> </div>
```

js:

```
html2canvas($('#aaa'), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
          var canv = $('<canvas />', { id: "avatar"});
          $('#tt').append(canv);
      var newImg = document.getElementById("avatar");
      newImg.src = canvas.toDataURL();
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/wtchz972/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/master/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
    #avatarCanvas{border:1px solid green;}

</style>
<script>
window.onload=(function(){

    var aaaDiv=document.getElementById('aaa');
    var ttDiv=document.getElementById('tt');

    html2canvas(aaaDiv).then(function(canvas) {
        // assign id:avatarCanvas to canvas 
        canvas.id='avatarCanvas';
        // append canvas to ttDiv
        ttDiv.appendChild(canvas);
    });

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>This is 'aaa'</h4>
    <div id="aaa">
        aaaaa
        <br>
        bbbbb
    </div> 
    <h4>This is 'tt'</h4>   
    <div id='tt'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is pretty much what Nish said, but also sets id='avatarCanvas'

Comment: marking this correct over Nish because assign an id is essential to me. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

In onrendered event function you will get canvas element, only you have to place it wherever you want.

```
html2canvas($('#aaa'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
    $(canvas).attr('id','avatar');
    $('#tt').append(canvas);
  }   
});
```

Refer this for more information..
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html

Comment: Upvote. We both came up with the same answer and you were a bit faster. You do need to set the id='avatarCanvas'

Comment: @Beki i have edited my answer for adding id,please check and accept the answer if it is correct.